# Factory functions in Golang

Tags: go, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, factory

I have a service object similar to the one shown below which is exposed through HTTP:

```
type ComputeService struct {

}

func (svc ComputeService) Compute(userType string, data Data) (Result, error) {
   // rate limit based on userType (both check and increment counter)
   // if not rate limited, compute and return result
}
```

Now, as you can see rate-limiting needs to be done based on `userType`. Implementation of rate limiter itself changes according to `userType`. I am thinking of 2 approaches of resolving the rate limiter using `userType`.

```
// First approach: for each request new ComputeService object is
// created after resolving RateLimiter using userType in the handler
// itself
type ComputeService struct {
    RateLimiter RateLimiter
}

// Second approach: ComputeService object is initialized during startup
// and only RateLimiter is resolved with every Compute() call by calling
// the provider function
type ComputeService struct {
    RateLimiterProvider func(userType string) RateLimiter
}
```

Both are testable. Which one would be preferable ? I'm leaning towards the 2nd approach since using it would mean that the handler will be purely read request, delegate to service, write out the response whereas in 1st approach, handler would contain additional step of resolving the rate limiter implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a DI system like [Dargo](https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo/) you can use its Provider injection to dynamically choose the implementation at runtime.

In that case your services would look something like the following:

```
import "github.com/jwells131313/dargo/ioc"

type RateLimiter interface {
}

type UserType1RateLimiter struct {
}

type UserType2RateLimiter struct {
}

type ComputeService struct {
    RateLimiterProvider ioc.Provider `inject:"RateLimiter"`
}

func (svc ComputeService) Compute(userType string, data Data) (Result, error) {
    // rate limit based on userType (both check and increment counter)
    // if not rate limited, compute and return result
    raw, err := svc.RateLimiterProvider.QualifiedBy(userType).Get()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    limiter := raw.(RateLimiter)
    //...
}
```

This is how you would bind these into the ServiceLocator:

```
func initializer() {
    serviceLocator, _ = ioc.CreateAndBind("ExampleLocator", func(binder ioc.Binder) error {
        binder.Bind("RateLimiter", UserType1RateLimiter{}).QualifiedBy("UserType1")
        binder.Bind("RateLimiter", UserType2RateLimiter{}).QualifiedBy("UserType2")
        binder.Bind("ComputeService", ComputeService{})
        return nil
    })
}
```

This only applies when you are using something like Dargo, but it still might be useful in your case.

If you are not using Dargo it seems to me to be a matter of opinion, although I personally would choose the second approach

Comment: Thanks for the answer. DI framework is not something i am considering. I am currently testing out the second pattern in a slightly complex code base. Till now it seems to be the best option. First approach made the handler contain lot of domain logic making it hard to test.